# In CQ5 is it possible to set whether a component renders by a property

Tags: aem

I have a component that we are working on, it's a series of preset form field components for a specific business group that can be configured via the dialog, so that they can set which field they need in a particular form.

There's a number of ways that I can go about implementing this, with the crudest being a series of if statements wrapping a cq:include. What I was trying to determine, if instead of doing this conditional check, I could have dialog update a property of the field component directly so that it doesn't render, without removing the object from the node structure.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may create a servlet filter with scope `INCLUDE` that skips processing all components with `hiddenProperty` set to `true`:

```
@SlingFilter(scope = SlingFilterScope.INCLUDE, order = Integer.MIN_VALUE)
public class HiddenResourceFilter implements Filter {

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
    if (request instanceof SlingHttpServletRequest) {
      SlingHttpServletRequest slingRequest = (SlingHttpServletRequest) request;
      ValueMap map = slingRequest.getResource().adaptTo(ValueMap.class);
      if (Boolean.parseBoolean(map.get("hiddenComponent", "false"))) {
        // we want to hide this component
        // so we don't call the doChain() method here
        return;
      }
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Comment: So it took me a while to accept this. Between writing the question and your response we had started to look at setting up a process to update the sling:resourceType with a new resource that would render nothing, and then when we wanted to return to rendering the component we would update the property back to what it was originally. This had a certain level of appeal to me as it would only affect that specific component, rather than a filter that would touch each include. Needless to say, we could make it work that way but the infrastructure was too large, and this is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

The rendering of components is part of the presentation layer, so you could use CSS for this!

You could use an arbitrary property on the field component called "shouldRender", which is editable via the dialog of the component. In the JSP of your component, you could do something like this :

```
<div id="field" <c:if test="${not shouldRender}">style="display: none;"</c:if>>
...
</div>
```

The CSS property "display: none;" hides an element, and it will not take up any space. The element will be hidden, and the page will be displayed as if the element is not there. However, the component will still be present in your node structure, which is exactly what you want!

Comment: I see where you are going with it, and it's an interesting approach, but I was trying to look for something that would avoid me writing out a series of conditional statements. If I was going to write a series of `if` statements, I would probably wrap the entire component.